# What's the complexity of " has(arr,ele) " function in Clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

What's the complexity of " has(arr,ele) " function in Clickhouse?

What's the complexity of " has(arr,ele) " function in Clickhouse?

Answer (score 0):

To solve `has(arr,ele)` Clickhouse reads all data from the column, uncompresses all data, checks each element of each array.

You may try to use bloom_filter skip index https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-queries-and-syntax/skip-indexes/skip-index-bloom_filter-for-array-column/